# Action-dependant Javascript/Jquery - how to activate a command only AFTER another script has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm working on my website and I decided it would be to my advantage to use 'designed' scroll bars instead of the ones browsers come with. I was lucky enough to come across this script http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar which basically does exactly what I need.

The only problem I've got is that I am trying to apply the custom scrollbars to some divs which are initially hidden and then toggle via a link div between hide/show.
As the programming page (http://www.hesido.com/flexcroll/flexcroll-programming.htm) explains, sometimes the scrollbar needs to be updated and/or manually applied, because being in hidden divs they do not load when the page opens.

I've checked my CSS and my HTML and the code works fine if the div is not hidden, so I am 100% that this has to do with the way I am hiding my divs.

The basic format for that is

`$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#iddiv').hide();});`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#id').click(function() {
      $('#iddiv').animate({
           height: 'toggle'
           }, 2000
      );
 });});
```

So I hide it initially, and then toggle it via a button.
Now, in this logic - the manual application of `fleXenv.fleXcrollMain("your-div-id");` should be somewhere above the last line of script (the one containing }); ).

This, however, either makes the div unscrollable or messes up the rest of my Javascript (scrollTo functions stop working, etc...)

**My question is, as a bit of a noobie JS user - WHERE do I need to place that piece of code that manually activates the custom scrollbar in my code  AFTER the toggle is activate and WHAT is the structure?**
By which I mean, does `fleXenv.fleXcrollMain("your-div-id");` stand on its own, does it need its own separate function, does it get a $ before it?

Loads of thanks to anyone who can help me with this! Final bit stopping me from launching my website.

UPDATE!
[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/KDe3M/) is the CSS/HTML and code for an example of what I am trying to achieve; because one of the files in the script needs to be downloaded to work, I think the only way is to copy and paste all the bits in a new HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `.animate()` function accepts more arguments. One of them is a function that gets called when the animation completes.

```
function activateScrollbar () {
    fleXenv.fleXcrollMain('iddiv');
}

$('#iddiv').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    },
    2000,
    activateScrollbar
);
```

You can also use an anonymous function, like this:

```
$('#iddiv').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    },
    2000,
    function () {
        fleXenv.fleXcrollMain('iddiv');
    }
);
```

Most functions in jQuery that include an animation, (like `.hide()` or `.fadeOut()`), allow you to pass a function that gets called when the animation completes. Most of these jQuery functions allow you to pass these extra arguments in a configuration object which can be more readable:

```
$('#iddiv').animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    },
    {
        duration: 2000,
        complete: function () {
            fleXenv.fleXcrollMain('iddiv');
        }
    }
);
```

See the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation for more details.

Here's a full example with the click behavior included:

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {

    $('#iddiv').animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        },
        {
            duration: 2000,
            complete: function () {
                fleXenv.fleXcrollMain('iddiv');
            }
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: that is a very detailed and educational answer, thank you very much. I have changed the code so that it now reads as above, but the result is still the same. This makes me wonder, considering what you wrote above, should the initiation of the scrollbar not be at the end of the 'click' action instead of the 'animate'one? Does 'click' accept more than one argument, or is there a different method for this. I'm not sure if you overlooked the click or if it is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @CasperF the click() function is similar to the animate() function in that accepts a function to call when something happens. but in the case of click, it happens instantly when the element is clicked. I updated my answer so you can see it in context. You can read it like: "1) when button is clicked 2) start an animation, 3) then when the animation completes activate the scrollbars". P.S. Don't forget to upvote answers you find helpful ;)

Comment: Absolutely no luck. I am quite sure the script is correct and the CSS/HTML requirements of the Scroll script are met. I'm led to believe it might be some other sort of bug with the artificial scroll bar.

Comment: I would definitely upvote, but I need reputation 15 for that an I am only on an 8 at the moment. This is really soul destroying; it's the only element of my website that is not working as expected and there's not much I can do about it with my knowledge. Unless I don't hide the divs, which means I lose the feel and style of navigation.

Comment: In fact, I've made a tryout HTML page with just the hidden container and basic CSS/HTML needed for the elements and the scroll bar is still not loading so it might be that the code has to be a bit different.

Comment: You may be having another issue that is unrelated to your question. I f you can post a demo somewhere I can take a look.

Comment: Thank you! I've uploaded a JFiddle of the isolated example here, but I am afraid it needs to be put in an HTML document after you've downloaded the JS from the fleXcroll website for it to work(or not work, as it isn't working):http://jsfiddle.net/KDe3M/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#id').click(function() {
      $('#iddiv').animate({
           height: 'toggle'
           }, 2000,
           function(){
               fleXenv.fleXcrollMain( $(this).attr('id') );
           }
      );
 });
```

That function is callback executed after `animate` function is complete.

Comment: hey! thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this didn't change anything; the toggle now functions normally, but the scroll bar is still the same.

Comment: Do you check all other things? All scripts and stylesheets are loaded properly? Maybe e.g. Firebug's console shows any errors? When I check it on my localhost, everything works ok. Btw you got typo in `$('##iddiv').hide();` there shouldn't be double #.